# Linux: Is there a limit for the number of fork() calls one process goup can issue? (Not per user!)

Tags: linux, process, java, limit, thread

We have a strange problem on a SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 12.5 system (kernel 4.12.14-122.60), which is the only KVM guest in a simliar KVM host:

One service started by systemd starts one program -> process which then forks an starts other programs -> child processes which again fork more programs -> child processes.

After appr. 50 or 60 forks including some JAVA children, this stops an all consecutive fork() calls from this process tree fail with errno=11 (ressource temp. unavail.).

A parallel running login session for the the same UID (user) can still create new processes, it can even start the programs that failed in the systemd initialized tree.

As far as I understand, the NPROC settings in /etc/security/limits.conf are system-wide limits for e.g. one UID. But here it looks as if there was a limit that pertains only to one parent process and its children and grand-children?

Is there such a limit, and how could we modify / extend it? Or could it be another parameter which is responsible indirectly for this behaviour?

Additional Info: This problem occurs only on one server installation that we have. All others work without problems. This one has 160 CPU cores and 128GB memory, all other have less than 50% of this. The default NPROC value on this system ist 628000 ...

Any hints or help appreciated.

Regards Stefan B.

PS: Found some similar problems dating back in 2016 for Arch-Linux, but I do not know if the solution using TasksMax applies here as well.

Comment: It is possible to set per-process limits with cgroups which can be done in several places, including systemd and in the kvm config.  But you could also be running out of some other resource, like ram...

Comment: Thx. It looks as if TasksMax woulf do the trick, and since this machine has nearly infinite resources, we will definitely not run out of memory if we increase DefaultTasksMax from 512 to 4096... But I am still looking for the appropriate KVM config?